# How to test random value in JsonArray using phpunit

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit

Hello Everyone I'm trying to test API and get the specific json element from the response, here is the response from the API :

```
{
  "Error": null,
  "Data": {
    "AuthToken": "jaskdfjlsadkfjasd",
    "InactiveTimeout": 20
  }
}
```

since the value of AuthToken is always random I can't test it using this code :

```
$this->post('/login',
    [
      'id'=>'1',
      'password'=>'secret',
    ])->seeJson([
      "Error" => null,
      'Data'=>array(
        'AuthToken'=>'',
        'InactiveTimeout'=>20)
       ]);
```

and I've tried using this code :

```
$this->post('/login',
    [
      'id'=>'1',
      'password'=>'secret',
    ])->seeJson([
      "Error" => null,
      'Data'=>array(
        'InactiveTimeout'=>20)
       ]);
```

but I can't pass the test, my question is how to write test for this case?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: One thing I would do using PHPUnit would be comparing the values using arrays with `assertArraySubset`. See this [link](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.assertions.html#appendixes.assertions.assertArraySubset) This way, you can compare if one array is inside the other.

Comment: Maybe you can try using `seeJson` for `Error` and `seeJsonStructure` for `AuthToken`.

Comment: @i906 yes using your suggestion will do the trick thanks, but is there any more clean way to achieve this? if not then I need to write two test for this kind of response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the code below:

```
$this->post('/login', [
        'id' => '1',
        'password' => 'secret',
    ])
    ->seeJson([
        'Error' => null
    ])
    ->seeJsonStructure([
        'Data' => [
            'AuthToken'
        ]
    ]);
```